# Spring MVC: NullReferenceException when generating form

Tags: forms, spring-mvc, nullreferenceexception

I'm having problems to figure out this problem. The exception is thrown when I try to go to /users/add url which should show the empty form for creating user entry. After that this exception is propagated throught the whole application.

Here is the controller code:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes(value = "user")
@RequestMapping(value = "/users")
public class UserController {

    @Inject
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getAllUsers() {
        List<User> users = userService.getAllUsers();

        return new ModelAndView("allUsers", "users", users);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView addUser(ModelMap map, @RequestParam(value = "id", required = false) Long id) throws EntityNotFoundException {
        User user = null;

        if(id != null) {
            user = userService.findById(id);

            if(user == null)
                throw new EntityNotFoundException("Can't find user!");
        }
        else {
            user = new User();
            user.setGender(Gender.MALE);
        }
        map.addAttribute("genders", generateGenders());

        return new ModelAndView("addUser", "user", user);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView addUser(ModelMap map, @Valid @ModelAttribute(value = "user") User user, BindingResult result,
            HttpServletResponse response, final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) throws IOException {
        if(!result.hasErrors()) {
            try {
                String userStatus = user.getId() != null ? "User Updated: " : "User Created: ";

                userService.saveOrUpdateUser(user);
                redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("userStatusMessage", userStatus + user.toString());

                return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("/users"));
            } catch (EntityNotFoundException e) {
                response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND, e.getMessage());

                return null;
            }
        }
        else {
            for (ObjectError error : result.getAllErrors()) {
                System.out.println(error.getObjectName() + ": " + error.getDefaultMessage());
            }
        }
        map.addAttribute("genders", generateGenders());

        return new ModelAndView("addUser", "user", user);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/delete", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView deleteUser(@RequestParam(value = "id", required = true) Long id,
            HttpServletResponse response, final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) throws IOException {
        try {
            User user = userService.deleteUser(id);
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("userStatusMessage", "Deleted User: " + user);
        } catch (EntityNotFoundException e) {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, e.getMessage());

            return null;
        }

        return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("/users"));
    }

    private Map<String, String> generateGenders() {
        Map<String,String> genders = new HashMap<String,String>();

        for (Gender gender : Gender.values()) {
            genders.put(gender.toString(), gender.getDisplayName());
        }

        return genders;
    }
}
```

And here is the error I get when I go to /users/add:

```
    HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /users/add. Reason:

    Server Error
Caused by:

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Calendar.setTime(Calendar.java:1106)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(SimpleDateFormat.java:955)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(SimpleDateFormat.java:948)
    at java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:336)
    at com.code9.data.User.toString(User.java:157)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2854)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:128)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractTemplateView.renderMergedOutputModel(AbstractTemplateView.java:146)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:263)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:475)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:514)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:920)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:403)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:184)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:856)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:1049)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:426)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:510)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.access$000(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:34)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:450)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: it gives a null pointer exception in User.java. Try to fix that.

Comment: I understand that null pointer is somewhere in User, but I don't know how to fix that. The problem is that it never comes to addUser(ModelMap map, @RequestParam(value = "id", required = false) Long id) where I set user object.

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/add") --- you have assigned the same value for two methods. is that right?

Comment: Yes. But one is for GET and other is for POST request method.

Comment: try to use logger. find whether it is coming into the methods. 
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(UserController .class);

logger.info("test");

Comment: Logger helped me to find what is causing problems. When I create a new user string and date fields are still null. The problem is that I don't know what is trying to read these values. Everything was working before I added SessionAttributes.

Comment: Please include `User` class in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem. It's inside toString() method of User class. I'm still not shure when it's called, because I don't call it explicitly. Sorry for inconvenience.

This is User toString() method before:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format("%d, %s %s, %s, %s, %s, %s", this.getId(), this.getFirstName(), this.getLastName(),
             new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(this.getBirthday()), this.getGender().getDisplayName(), this.getPersonalNumber(),
             this.getEmail());
}
```

And this is a fix:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format("%d, %s %s, %s, %s, %s, %s", this.getId(), this.getFirstName(), this.getLastName(),
             this.getBirthday() == null ? "" : new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(this.getBirthday()), this.getGender().getDisplayName(), this.getPersonalNumber(),
             this.getEmail());
}
```